# How do I register my Skylanders?

Tags: skylanders

I need to find the webcodes associated with my son's skylanders.  I connected the portal of power while on skylanders.com and activision.com but the skylander didn't appear like I had read about.  Apparently I need very specific instructions.

Answer (score 3):

Skylanders Universe, the website where you could play with your Skylanders online, was closed a few weeks ago and rendered the web codes unusable on PC, you can still use the codes on the Skylanders mobile games.

If you've lost your web codes, [the only way to retrieve them is now unavailable](http://support.activision.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/Skylanders-Universe-FAQ#6), however if you do have the physical toys and wish to play with them on the mobile games, you'll need a Bluetooth portal specifically for iOS devices.

Answer (score -2):

You can look at them in swap force... And I think trap team but I haven't checked superchargers.

Comment: di you think you can give more details? you can look at them in the game.. but where? how?